# Centering webpages horizontally and vertically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, centering

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code? I'm trying to center my webpages vertically and horizontally but this isn't working! It's not centering for me.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>String Functions</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.fn.center = function() {
     this.css("position", "absolute");
     this.css("top", ($(document).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(document).scrollTop() + "px");
     this.css("left", ($(document).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(document).scrollLeft() + "px");
    return this;
    };

    $("#d1").center();
    </script>       
</head>

<body>

<div id="d1" style="background-color:red;width:100px; height: 100px;"></div>    

</body>
```

Comment: what problem are you seeing?  I dont see one... I changed window to document.  http://jsfiddle.net/euALd/

Comment: Hello, it's just not centering for me at all. The above code is what I have.

Comment: It's working for me as well.  What browser are you using? And does the console throw an error?

Comment: hello, i've tried firefox, safari, but no luck and no errors!

Comment: REALLY???  I tried it in firefox, IE8, and chrome and they all render fine with the link I provided above!  http://jsfiddle.net/euALd/

Comment: Hi CrazyDart, I made another document and dropped in your code...please see above. But I'm still not getting the centering. I know I'm doing something wrong! Does everything look correct above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function() {
    this.css({
        "position" : "absolute",
        "top" : "50%",
        "left" : "50%",
        "margin-left" : (this.width() / 2) * -1,
        "margin-top" : (this.width() / 2) * -1
    });
};
```

A very reliable way to center an absolutely positioned element is to set its position from the left or top to 50%, and then its margin to -half the width or height of the object.